# Load data from one file to the other based on the matching part in two files

Tags: python, append, strip, temp, startswith

**input1**

```
>Aa,Ab,Ac,ET0001
>Ba,Bb,Bc,ET0002
>Ca,Cb,Cc,ET0003
```

**input2**

```
>Infor_a, aa:dfkvl, bb:csd, cc:ET0001
sldcksdlksjelkjfslkdjflskdjflskd
sldkcmowdimnwo
>Infor_b, aa:coeq, bb:ock, cc:ET0056
lskdjocisnmodk
>Infor_c, aa:vwjm, bb:cxj, cc:ET0751
spodcisdokfmnwoke
woeinmfwoeinflsdkvm
sldknmflwkenmlwk
>Infor_d, aa:wokx, bb:rkx, cc:ET0003
sodicjsodijsoi
```

**Expected output**

```
>Aa,Ab,Ac,ET0001
sldcksdlksjelkjfslkdjflskdjflskd
sldkcmowdimnwo
>Ba,Bb,Bc,ET0002
NaN
>Ca,Cb,Cc,ET0003
sodicjsodijsoi
```

**Code**

```
with open(input1, 'r') as fr1, open(input2, 'r') as fr2, open(output, 'w') as fw:

    temp = []
    while (fr2):
        line2 = fr2.readline()

        if line2.startswith('>'):
            templist  = line2.strip().split()
            for element in templist:
                if element.startswith('cc:ET'):
                    replaced_element = element.replace('cc:','')
                    temp.append(replaced_element)

        if not line2:
            break
```

I add the data (start with 'ET' from 'input2') in a template.

1. I want to get the information under '>' that matches 'ETnumber' in 'input2'.
   2.If there is a match between 'ETnumber' and 'input1', I want to write the information under '>' under each line of 'input1'.

Do you have any suggestion for me, the next step from my code(with os.listdir)?

Comment: Are you sure you want the literal text "NaN" written to your output file?

Comment: @DarkKnight Yeah! the literal text 'NaN'! It will be fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a functional improvement over the excellent offering from @mozway but rather takes a step-by-step approach that may be simpler for a novice to understand:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

TILDE = '~'
DIR = 'logan'
HOME = os.path.expanduser(TILDE)
NAN = 'NaN\n'
CC = 'cc:'

I_1 = dict()

with open(os.path.join(HOME, DIR, 'input1.txt')) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        t = line.strip().split(',')
        I_1[t[-1]] = t

I_2 = defaultdict(list)
k = TILDE

with open(os.path.join(HOME, DIR, 'input2.txt')) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            i = line.find(CC)
            if i >= 0:
                k = line[i+len(CC):].strip().split(',')[0]
        else:
            I_2[k].append(line)

with open(os.path.join(HOME, DIR, 'output1.txt'), 'w') as outfile:
    for k, v in I_1.items():
        print(f'{",".join(v)}', file=outfile)
        print(f'{"".join(I_2.get(k, NAN))}', file=outfile, end='')
```

Comment: I really appreciate you sir! I'm sorry but, in the 2nd step(input2), how would your code change if the '>' line was of this form? --> >Infor_a, aa:dfkvl, bb:csd, cc:ET0001, dd:sdcsd, ee:wecf

Comment: Sir! I changed!!!  k = line.strip().split(' ')[-3].replace('cc:', '') like this

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to hold the matches in f2, then a simple loop:

```
import re
with open(input1, 'r') as fr1, open(input2, 'r') as fr2, open(output, 'w') as fw:
    values = dict(re.findall('(ET\d+)\n([^>]+)', f2.read()))
    for line in f1:
        fw.write(line)
        fw.write(values.get(line.rsplit(',',1)[-1],'NaN\n'))
```

output:

```
>Aa,Ab,Ac,ET0001
sldcksdlksjelkjfslkdjflskdjflskd
sldkcmowdimnwo
>Ba,Bb,Bc,ET0002
NaN
>Ca,Cb,Cc,ET0003
sodicjsodijsoi
```

NB. like in your previous question, do not do your weird:

```
while (f):
    line = f.readline()
    ...
    if not line:
        break
```

Just do:

```
for line in f:
    ...
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. I will try to use for loop more than while loop.